# pycharmにkerasをインストールした後のtracebackエラー

Tags: python, keras

環境:pyhton3.9  virtualenv　グローバルsite-packageを継承 →kerasをインストールして一文書いて実行してみたのですが、この「traceback」エラーは何が間違っているのかわかりません。単にインストール先が違っていたり、インストールできていないだけでしょうか？[image]

Comment: スクリーンショットかつエラーメッセージのウインドウが見切れていて情報が不十分です。全文をテキストでコピペしてください。

Comment: 解決しました。サポートされているパッケージの中でインストールされていないものがあったようです。